# React Mobile redirect Loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a pretty annoying issue I'm not able to fix for some reason. I just published a new
[Website](https://wood-in-vision.com) made in react. For the Mobile version I set up a Redirect to the "m." subdomain. Now I have the issue that it works on IOS but it's stuck in a redirect loop on Android. Does anyone know why that is? It's made with a Redirect script and react-device-detect

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Page from "./Page";
import Footer1 from "./Footer";
import "./style.css";
import Datenschutz from "./Datenschutz";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, } from "react-router-dom";
import ScrollToTop from "./Router-Scripts/ScrollToTop"
import Impressum from "./Impressum";
import Kontakt from "./Kontakt";
import PageScrollProgressBar from "react-page-scroll-progress-bar";
import { Scrollbars } from 'react-custom-scrollbars-2';
import About from "./AboutUs";
import { BrowserView, MobileView, } from 'react-device-detect';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function Redirect() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.replace('https://m.wood-in-vision.com');
    }, 0);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, []);
  return <>Redirecting</>;
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MobileView>
        <Redirect />
      </MobileView>
      <BrowserView>
        <PageScrollProgressBar color="#009900" bgColor="transparent" height="5.2rem" />
        <Scrollbars />
        <Router>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Navbar />
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Page />} />
          </Routes>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/datenschutz" element={<Datenschutz />} />
          </Routes>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/impressum" element={<Impressum />} />
          </Routes>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/kontakt" element={<Kontakt />} />
          </Routes>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          </Routes>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Footer1 />
        </Router>
      </BrowserView>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I forgot to add `navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)` to the mobile site works now